# How can I generate a test report with Chutzpah?

Tags: javascript, qunit, chutzpah

I would like to generate a junit, nunit or mstest report for my QUnit javascript unit tests and because we are mainly developing in Visual Studio (c# MVC server), we currently are using Chutzpah to run the QUnit tests.

Now I would like to generate a test report to integrate in Jenkins, but i couldn't find a simple way not involving writing an own report generator.

Does somebody know of an alternative to Chutzpah, which can run QUnit tests headless and integrates into Visual Studio **or** a way this can be solved with Chutzpah?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chutzpah 2.1 (released on 9/8/2012) now supports outputting a junit-xml compatible file. From the command line you specify `/junit <filename>` and it will spit out the correct xml format.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hi Matthew, Thanks a lot it works just as I hoped it would work. :-D I've just got one issue, because I'm calling Chutzpah with MSBuild (64-bit):
I'm getting a `System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid` ... `at Chutzpah.RunnerCallbacks.StandardConsoleRunnerCallback.ClearCounter()` ...
I could workaround this exception, if I added the /silent flag to the call.
Should I add a bug to your codeplex issue tracker?

Comment: The `/silent` command line option is the correct solution. It stops Chutzpah from trying to show a pretty running test count which causes issues when running from msbuild or ant.